# Error "Cannot find a parameter with this name: brush" in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I copied the below code from [BrushExampleSnippet.kt](https://github.com/android/snippets/blob/337e77d592712ddb6f207e157607e43d0c62dfe8/compose/snippets/src/main/java/com/example/compose/snippets/graphics/BrushExampleSnippets.kt#L252-L285) but the compiler gives an error that it can't find `brush`, I double checked import but it's correct as `import androidx.compose.ui.text.TextStyle`.

```
    // Use ImageShader Brush with TextStyle
    Text(
        text = "Hello Android!",
        style = TextStyle(
            brush = imageBrush, // here brush parameter is not found.
            fontWeight = FontWeight.ExtraBold,
            fontSize = 36.sp
        )
    )
```

[image]

Comment: Which version of compose are you using? Brush API was added to TextStyle by compose 1.2.0.

Comment: Yeah, thanks, it's working now. Actually, whenever I create a new compose project it gets compose version `1.1.1` by default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brush API was added to `TextStyle` by compose **1.2.0**.